# how to resolve error "Text Line Should not be null" while comparing two DB using VSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi i am using VSTS2010 to compare two build using schema compare. today encounter an error while compairing "Text line should not be null" and suddenly got error "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close." can somebody please help me to resolve this error. Thanks! in advanaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue need to install "DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi"